# Disabling scaled x ticks causes "Dimension too large" in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

I want to change my x axis tick labels to read `0K 20K 40K 60K 80K` similar to my y axis tick labels in this chart:

[image]

My LaTeX MVP generating the image:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
iter;prod
0;-10589.143027099373
2080;-10137.34268961796
5948;-9823.312236854963
8461;-9531.740064852165
11565;-9374.010299137673
14779;-9174.160659364205
18133;-8812.173184097246
21281;-8524.717622361832
24346;-8334.931265113803
28693;-8260.530715627245
33657;-8144.811407051079
37692;-8026.3359694899145
41347;-7927.802055824076
45664;-7854.28445759018
50737;-7837.35420135146
54924;-7697.667649897329
59341;-7681.064772064068
64499;-7460.053337376205
71204;-7385.997574969703
76470;-7330.933540294809
78661;-7315.709786834038
81232;-7232.586421626356
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
        ymax=0,
        xticklabel = {
            \pgfmathparse{\tick/1000}
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,K
        },
%        scaled x ticks=false,
        yticklabel = {
            \pgfmathparse{\tick/1000}
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,K
        },
        scaled y ticks=false,
    ]
    \addplot +[blue,mark=none] table [x=iter, y=prod, col sep=semicolon] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now when I uncomment the line `scaled x ticks=false,` I receive this error:

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.50     \end{axis}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.50     \end{axis}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on build/mvp.log.
```

This error message seems to be associated with divisions by zero. Due to my set denominator of `1000` I don't see how that could the cause. Therefore I have no idea why this method works for the y axis but not for the x axis. Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

**Update: axes with `scaled ticks=base 10:-3,`**

Based on BambOo's suggestion:
[image]

Comment: You error is more likely related to the fact that you handle relatively large numbers for the default TeX math engine. IMHO it is unnecessary to ad a  `K` to each ticklabel, why do you not use it in the label ? e.g. `xlabel={money [\si{\kilo\euro}]` using the `siunitx` package

Comment: By default the x tick labels are `0 2 4 6 8` and at the end there is a `* 10^4` which is added in a new line. I want to avoid this type of visualization. Changing it to `0 20,000 40,000 60,000 80,000` is also not an option because it uses too much space.

Comment: So I'd still have to divide the tick labels by 1000 even if I move the `K` from the tick labels to the axis label. I tried that by removing the `K` from my code and `lualatex` still exists with the same error.

Comment: If tikc labels `0 20 40 60 80` is what you look for, simply use `axis` option `scaled ticks=base 10:-3` instead of your custom `xticklabel/yticklabel `

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added `scaled ticks=base 10:-3,` to my axis and rendered the chart. I added a screenshot to the question. Now it shows `* 10^3` instead of `* 10^4`. Is there another way I can hide this? I'd rather have a `K` appended to each axis label because to me they feel less "out of place".

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of `\pgfmathparse` held the answer:

> The math engine in pgf typically uses TEX’s internal arithmetics. That means: it is well suited for
>   numbers in the range [−16384, 16384] and has a precision of 5 digits
>
> The number range is typically too small for plotting applications. pgfplots improves the number range
>   by means of `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}\pgfmathparse{1+41}` to activate the “floating point unit” (fpu) and
>   to apply all following operations in floating point.

Adding `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}` into my blocks for `xticklabel` and `yticklabel` allows for the calculations required to render my axis as I want it to.